# What is the typical "mileage" for a gasoline chainsaw?

Tags: tools, tool-maintenance, chainsaw

I want to roughly compare a gasoline-powered chainsaw to a battery-powered one. I can't find any quotes on how many cuts (and of what specific material) a gasoline chainsaw can do on some specific amount of gasoline.

What I'm looking for looks like this: *chainsaw model X (any will do for my rough comparison) can cut L logs of diameter D (or M 2x4-s or any other specific amount of any specific amount of lumber stuff) on Y milliliters (or any other specific amount figure) of gasoline*.

Are there any quotes like that - either from manufacturers or from real life experience?

Comment: You might have a tough time finding that info now, but it looks like the EPA is working on it.  [Regulatory Announcement](http://www.epa.gov/otaq/regs/nonroad/equip-ld/hhsfrm/f00007.htm). [Lawn and Garden (Small Gasoline) Equipment](http://www.epa.gov/otaq/equip-ld.htm).

Comment: My chainsaw gets 36 MPG, if I run with it.

Answer (score 6):

This is a good question, but I'm not sure it's answerable. (Or, if it is answerable, you'll get answers from controlled experiments that will be useless to compare to real-world usage.)

I know from experience that my gas-powered saw will run for about 30-40 minutes on a tank of gas when I'm bucking logs for firewood. That's running at more or less full throttle for a significant portion of that time -- I move from cut to cut rapidly because the logs are mostly ready to cut.

But it's hard to know how much wood (i.e. measured in cords) I'm going to actually cut in that time, because the mix of logs (species, age/seasoning, size) isn't uniform and the chain dulls over a couple-hour cutting session. Even on a single cut, I know that the saw will zip through a 4" hemlock that's been down a year but will take forever to work both sides of an ancient 30+" maple that's full of knots.

Finally, performance of the saw will depend on how well you maintain it. Again from experience I know that if I haven't done my job properly (sharpening, cleaning, etc) then it doesn't run as well or cut as well. I occasionally think, "Oh just one more tank of gas", and regret it because it doesn't cut for beans and my time would have been better spent in the garage sharpening and/or cleaning the machine so it runs smoothly & cuts fast.

Comment: Results from controlled experiments are okay - the quote for the electric saw is also from a controlled experiment.

Comment: I think it would require control experiments to benchmark different ones. Unless a magazine wants to do a review (like PC review magazines benchmark printers/etc) I don't think it will happen. And the Gov/EPA have better things to do (unlike car mileages).

Answer (score 0):

The mileage depends on a lot of factor including chainsaw power, sharpness, wood type and finally operator's skill.

However, this is my personal experience. With my Husqvarna 460 Rancher Gas Chainsaw(24 Inch), I can cut 2 cord of wood with one full tank gas.